# C# Set array memberInfo without generic cast

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

```
if(fieldInfo.FieldType.IsArray)
{
    Type elementType = fieldInfo.FieldType.GetElementType();
    obj[] objs = MyCustomConverter.Convert(elementType, IEnumerable<string> input);
    field.SetValue(target,objs);
}
```

The `SetValue` step will throw an exception because the value(`objs`) to be set does not match the specific type. But the hardest part is that I don't know what type the array exactly is. All I have is non-generic.
So I cannot call something like `Cast<T>` (I don't have that generic `T` but I have `typeof(T)`).  And `Array.ConvertAll(objs,obj=> Convert.ChangeType(obj, elementType))` makes no sense since it still returns `object[]` and my custom converter has already converted the input elements to the right element type!! It's just that the array itself is wrapped. Is there a way to do such hack as `object array = SomeFunc(Type arrayType, object[] elements);` ?

What should I do to set the array field successfully?
(I hope I made myself clear :P)

Comment: do you mean `objs` array is type of `object[]` or its some thing else?(what is `obj[]`)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary yes the elements are wrapped as `object`

Comment: do you mean you want to check what is the type of each element in `objs` array since its not known? you want to check for type and then perform correct operation?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Nah! I know the element type, but not generic. So I cannot set the correct array type.

Comment: i did not understand well.but i guess you need Array or ArrayList. then you dont need to set type for each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I think I figured out! Here is the solution:

```
object[] array = obj[] objs = MyCustomConverter.Convert(elementType, IEnumerable<string> input);
Array wrappedArray = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, array.Length);
array.CopyTo(wrappedArray, 0);
field.SetValue(target,wrappedArray);
```

It's just that I didn't know an array can created by `Array.CreateInstance` rather than `T[]`(like `int[]`)